# Result of JOIN is longer than the limit of 50,000 characters

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to combine text from column A and match it with each possibility of column B.I used the formulas:

in C1:

```
=transpose(split(join("", arrayformula(rept(filter(A1:A, len(A1:A))&char(9999), counta(B1:B)))), char(9999)))
```

in D1:

```
=transpose(split(rept(join(char(9999), filter(B1:B, len(B1:B)))&char(9999), counta(A1:A)), char(9999)))
```

but when I use it in my list I get these errors in C1 and D1 respectively;

> Text result of JOIN is longer than the limit of 50000 characters
>   Text result of REPT is longer than the limit of 32000 characters

I tested this out with a smaller list of just:

```
a b c 1 2
```

and managed to get my list to generate this after combining the two cells:

```
a 1
a 2
a 3
b 1
b 2
b 3
```

but the list I am combining has a lot more text in each of the columns.

Any suggestions on how to combine my lists as shown above but with 132 possibilities in column A and 52 possibilities in column B?

Each line has between 70 and 150 characters of text in each row.

Answer (score 4):

Go to menu `Tools → Script Editor...`

Paste this code:

```
function crossJoin(arr1, arr2, delim) {

  delim = delim || '';

  var result = [];
  var row = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
      row = [];
      row.push('' + arr1[0,i] + delim + arr2[0,j]);
      result.push(row);
    }   
  }
  return result;
}
```

Save project.

Use it as regular function in spreadsheet:

`=crossJoin(A1:A132,B1:B52)`

Optionaly use delimeter:

`=crossJoin(A1:A132,B1:B52, "-")`

Comment: this worked!!!!!!!!!! thank you so much!!!! this saves me so much time. The original formula I was using worked if I was using a small data set. but I put this in and got all 6000+ items. You are fantastic.

Comment: This seems to not work anymore. My scripted function still suffers from the 50 000 characters limitation.