# Text result of JOIN is longer than the limit of 50000 characters

Tags: google-sheets

I'm running a formula to **join, split, and count** items in a column.

> =query(transpose(split(join(";", filter(Inventory!J2:J, len(Inventory!J2:J))), ";", False)), "select Col1, count(Col1) group
>   by Col1", 0)

It was working brilliantly until I hit this character limit. Any ideas how to get around it?

Sample, editable shared spreadsheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QQsiQVrrAZnmvR5dMK0SHIP3xDTObUFMPIHW56QOoMQ/edit?usp=sharing

Also, there is a similar question here, though I couldn't make it work for mine: [Google sheets Text result of JOIN is longer than the limit of 50000 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42475415/google-sheets-text-result-of-join-is-longer-than-the-limit-of-50000-characters)

Comment: See answers: here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368544/new-google-spreadsheet-concatenate-limit-50000-characters

Comment: Yes, I saw that. Hoping for a simpler solution.

Comment: I'm still looking for an answer to this. I was unable to make the script in the above link work in this situation.

Comment: The question is closed and I can't answer it here. Please see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48163806/5372400