# Google Sheets Cross Join Function Tables with More than Two Columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

The crossJoin function posted by @Max Makhrov from the below thread works almost completely for what I was hoping to achieve. It was in response to cross joining two columns and I tried joining two tables, one with two columns and one with five columns. It works but only partially.

1. The delimiter of the column data is stuck as comma ",". This could be problematic for values with commas. The delimiter variable in the function only defines the two ranges being joined.
2. If the column being joined is a date for example, it seems to extend out the full date text inclusive of time zone and fixed as text. Is there a way to allow for it to be non-text to be formatted? Even when it's parsed using the split() function it's definitely still text.

[Result of JOIN is longer than the limit of 50,000 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42475415/result-of-join-is-longer-than-the-limit-of-50-000-characters)

Below is a link to the example input and output. The first output example is a standard cross join. The other is the actual desired output which filters for any data rows where the date in column 5 is greater than or equal to the date in column 2.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FGS8lYyy60AH49Qyug8Uxaey5jxDksihOks7ll8Hq10/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: If you share a short sample of the data and the desired output, i think i can give you the output you want with a formula instead of a script.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: posted edited and sample found in the shared sheet. @MattKing formula didn't work because of the character limit but if you have a way to get around that w/o a function that would be great.

Comment: Your spreadsheet - Access denied.

Comment: Link updated try again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your spreadsheet is View Only, so i can't demo it there, but try this.  On the demo sheet, start a new tab, then put this formula in cell A2.

Happy to walk you through it a bit if it works.  Otherwise, maybe make the sample editable so i can troubleshoot w/ you in the same place?

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({HLOOKUP({"A","B"},{"A","B";Sheet1!A5:B},SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!D5:D)*COUNTA(Sheet1!A5:A),1,0)/COUNTA(Sheet1!D5:D)+2),HLOOKUP({"D","E","F","G"},{"D","E","F","G";Sheet1!D5:G},MOD(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(Sheet1!D5:D)*COUNTA(Sheet1!A5:A),1,0),COUNTA(Sheet1!D5:D))+2)},"where Col2>=Col5"))
```

Comment: Share settings changed on sample and I was able to demonstrate the concept on the MK.help tab